# Check box value doesn't come

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error in selecting multiple rows by checkbox error Undefined index: checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260181/error-in-selecting-multiple-rows-by-checkbox-error-undefined-index-checkbox)

Im going to select multiple rows by checkbox but the checkbox value doesn't take to the variable $del_id is always null..Why is that? pleas help me

```
     <td><input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $row["file_serial_id"]; ?>" /><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]"  value="<?php echo $row['file_serial_id']?>" /></td>
 if(isset($_POST['send_btn']) and $_POST['send_btn']=="Send"){
    $checkbox = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? $_POST['checkbox'] : 0; 
     $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox']; //from name="checkbox[]"
            $countCheck = count($_POST['checkbox']);
    for($i=0;$i<$countCheck;$i++){
        $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
        $sql2 = "UPDATE retained_file_mst SET mark_to_dispose=1 WHERE file_serial_id='$del_id'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2,$conn);
        }
// if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php
if($result2){
echo "success";
}else{
    echo "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. You are doing count.. on what???

Comment: your code will only say success/error on the last query you did

Comment: Note that this script is vulnerable to SQL injection, and you don't appear to be doing any check of ownership over the records you are about to delete. Any user could post any values via a script, and delete all the records in your database.  For the injection, at a minimum you need to be calling `mysql_real_escape_string()` on variables used in your query.  Fixing the ownership is a lot more complicated.

Comment: count is to get the number of selected checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if( (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) && (is_array($_POST['checkbox'])) )
{
    while(list($key,$value)=each($_POST['checkbox'])) 
    {
        $sql="UPDATE retained_file_mst SET mark_to_dispose=1 WHERE file_serial_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'";
        mysql_query($sql,$conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: this shows an error and warning
 Undefined variable: checkbox in C:\wamp\www\TEMPLATE\fileDisposalResults.php on line 20
and 
Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in C:\wamp\www\TEMPLATE\fileDisposalResults.php on line 23